# Set image for contact iOS

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I am using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` for representation table of contacts. By tapping contact I need to set new image for it. I added code to delegate for changing person data, but can't change image. Any suggestions?

This is my code below:

```
 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.theImage);
    CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
    CFErrorRef error;

    ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error); // clean any image first from ref
    if (ABAddressBookSave(_addressBook, &error))
    {
        ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error);
        ABAddressBookSave(_addressBook, &error);
    }
    CFRelease(cfdata);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    return NO;
}
```

I downloaded sample from here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html)

To check how it works you can download code and modify delegate below with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the changes via `ABAddressBookSave()`

Also, keep in mind if your contact does NOT already have an image, both the thumbnail and the full sized image will be added when you use `ABPersonSetImageData`. However, if your contact has a full-sized image already, *only* the thumbnail will be set when you use`ABPersonSetImageData`.

```
// this is not production level code. method call return values and errors
// need to be handled properly
ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error); // clean any image first from ref
if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error))
{
   ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error);
   ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments I have updated my question with code based on your comments but I still don't see that image appears in my contact. I have checked cfdata, person, _addressBook all of them have value

Comment: i have added link to sources from where I downloaded it

Comment: I think I have used different address book reference. I get instance of address book from ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and it works good. Thanks